# Changes made to airflow.cfg file not reflecting when running Airflow using Ubuntu

Tags: airflow, ubuntu-18.04, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have created a Dag file and saved it in the airflow home folder(C:\ubuntu\rootfs\home\admin123\airflow\dags) but it didn't show up in the web UI. So I tried to change the dag folder from the airflow.cfg file. This is the new dags folder location(/c/users/myuser/airflowhome/dags/)

After doing this change I restarted the scheduler and webserver in Ubuntu but still, my Dag file is not showing in the web UI.

I'm using the Airflow 2.2.5 version and Ubuntu 18.04 version.